# JavaFX fix "see through" Triangle mesh

Tags: java, javafx

so I am importing glTF format into JavaFX. I'm experiencing a weird effect where I can see through the Triangle mesh and see other parts of it / see other meshes through it.
A few Pics
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

It would be fantastic if someone knows a solution to this. I already tried using CullFace.Front and CullFace.Back.

Here is the code the generate the Triangle Meshes:

```
package fx;

import gltf.GLTFParseException;
import gltf.mesh.GLTFMesh;
import gltf.mesh.GLTFMeshPrimitive;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.shape.CullFace;
import javafx.scene.shape.MeshView;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class FXglTFMesh extends Group {

public static FXglTFMesh fromGLTFMesh(GLTFMesh mesh) throws GLTFParseException {
    FXglTFMesh fxMesh = new FXglTFMesh();


    GLTFMeshPrimitive[] primitives = mesh.getPrimitives();
    MeshView[] meshViews = new MeshView[primitives.length];
    for (int i = 0;i < meshViews.length; i++){
        meshViews[i] = fromPrimitive(primitives[i]);
    }

    FXglTFMaterial material;

    fxMesh.getChildren().addAll(meshViews);
    return fxMesh;
}

private static MeshView fromPrimitive(GLTFMeshPrimitive primitive) throws GLTFParseException {
    TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
    MeshView view = new MeshView(mesh);
    view.setCullFace(CullFace.BACK);

    //Reading texture coords
    float[][] texCoords = convertArrayToNested(2, 
    primitive.getAttribute().getTexCoord_0().readDataAsFloats());
    mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(primitive.getAttribute().getTexCoord_0().readDataAsFloats());

    if (primitive.getIndices() != null){
        //Mesh is indexed
        mesh.getPoints().addAll(primitive.getAttribute().getPosition().readDataAsFloats());

        int[] indices = primitive.getIndices().readDataAsInts();

        for (int i = 0;i < indices.length; i+=3){
            mesh.getFaces().addAll(indices[i], 0, indices[i+1], 0, indices[i+2], 0);
        }
    } else {
        //Mesh is not indexed
        //Parse the vertices and faces
        float[][] vertices = convertArrayToNested(3, 
primitive.getAttribute().getPosition().readDataAsFloats());

        for (int i = 0;i < vertices.length; i+=3){
            mesh.getPoints().addAll(vertices[i]);
            mesh.getPoints().addAll(vertices[i+1]);
            mesh.getPoints().addAll(vertices[i+2]);
            //add 3 points
            mesh.getFaces().addAll(i,i,  i+1,i+1,  i+2,i+2 ); //Add those three points as face
        }
    }
    //Material
    FXglTFMaterial material = FXglTFMaterial.fromGLTFMaterial(primitive.getMaterial());
    view.setMaterial(material);
    return view;
}

private static float[][] convertArrayToNested(int factor, float[] array){
    float[][] floats = new float[array.length / factor][];

    for (int i = 0;i < floats.length; i++){
        int dataOffset = i * factor;
        floats[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, dataOffset, dataOffset+factor);
    }

    return floats;
}
```

}

Full code: https://github.com/NekoLvds/GLTFImporter (Development branch)

Comment: It looks like there is no depth buffering being used to make sure that triangles that are in front of others are rendered on top. Your code appears to just render them in the order that they are stored in the mesh.

Comment: Based on [this code](https://github.com/NekoLvds/GLTFImporter/blob/master/src/main/java/test/MainApp.java#L30) it looks like @CatCraft959 is correct. You need to create the scene [with depth buffering enabled](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing)).

Comment: @CatCraft959 thank you very much that solved the issue :D

Comment: @Slaw thank you very much on further explaining what catCraft said. That helped a lot